# Django and Dynamic Example Data

Tags: django, json, django-fixtures

I'm trying to find a way to easily generate an example/demonstration data set from `initial_data.json` in Django.

Essentially, the fixtures and `initial_data.json` do exactly what I need, except that the dates are static....

My app uses dates to display/sort otherwise easily generated information (comments, scores etc) and I'd like to create a thorough data set in order to be able to demonstrate the app's functions to prospective clients; the problem arises with the dates. Even if I run `syncdb` (which automatically includes my `initial_data.json`), the dates are static, so all the information will relate to those specific dates, rather than to today. As time passes, that data will become less visible in the app and will therefore not fully demonstrate it's abilities to potential clients.

Is there an easy way to update date information in `initial_data.json` so that dates remain relevant to the current real date and I can then run syncdb again with those new dates? (Assume that this is all on a local machine merely as a demonstration to clients... Not on a server, production or otherwise).

I hope this makes sense?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, my solution was to use django-mockups: https://github.com/sorl/django-mockups

It adds random data to your tables (all of them or only those specified by the user) by obeying the field types (text, email, url etc) and the max_length specified in those fields. Inserts Lorem Ipsum and inserts correctly formatted email address etc etc

Very easy to use, can be set to run through a cron job, or can be run manually as and when required. Perfect.

Answer (score 0):

you might be better off writing a function (maybe a management command) to generate some dummy data and save to your (temporary?) database

Comment: Thanks second - can that function use initial_data.json as a base? That way I can still write the static data once and get the function to simply update the dates....?

Comment: it's just code so it can do what you want. e.g. set `foo_date` on all `Bar` models to `yesterday` or `next_tuesday`